# Using React hook to run Mobx method before initial render of component

Tags: reactjs, mobx, react-hooks

As the title suggests, i have my state inside a Mobx store. I have an async method (action) that fetches the data and stores it in a property inside the store, from where i will access it in the necessary component.

Problem is, currently the property will be undefined on the initial component render - resulting in an error in the component.

How do i make use of `useEffect()` so that it runs an async method once and only once - and before the initial component render, ensuring the state will be available for `return()`? Something like this:

```
const Workflow = () => {
    const store = useContext(WorkflowContext)

    useEffect(async () => {
        await store.getWorkflow()
    }, [])
...
```

Comment: Don't write the component in a way that will result in error on `undefined`. It's `...` that is relevant.

Comment: I have an async router with a suspense fallback component acting as a "loading indicator". The router has a route for the Workflow component. I was hoping to find a way to avoid implementing ui loading logic twice.

Comment: Then you have XY problem. It's impossible to pause the initialization of a component, with or without hooks. `getWorkflow` possibly needs to be called at higher level. Consider reasking the question with all relevant parts involved, including async router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the property in the store is `undefined` and return `null` from the component if that is the case.

**Example**

```
const Workflow = () => {
  const store = useContext(WorkflowContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    store.getWorkflow();
  }, []);

  if (store.someProperty === undefined) {
    return null;
  }
  return <div>{store.someProperty}</div>;
};
```